# VueJS date piker Vuetify listener

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, listener, computed-properties

I need your help to solve a problem I am facing.

I am currently working with a computed on Vue.js, however I want to use a listener instead of this computed.

Do you know how I can switch from one to the other?

Thank you in advance.

```js
import { MUTATION_entreePlanningCreate } from "./graphql/mutations";

export default {
  name: "EntreePlanningForm",
  data: function () {
    return {
      dates: ["", ""],
      datesRules: [(v) => !!v || "Veuillez selectionner une date"],
      label: "",
      labelRules: [
        (v) => v.length < 20 || "Le champ doit comporter moin de 20 caractère",
      ],
      description: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    envoyer: function () {
      if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {
        this.$apollo
          .mutate({
            mutation: MUTATION_entreePlanningCreate,
            variables: {
              input: this.input,
            },
          })
          .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
          });
      }
    },
  },

  computed: {
    input() {
      return {
        dateDebut: this.dates[0],
        dateFin: this.dates[1],
        label: "",
        description: "",
      };
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? when dates are selected then do some actions?
there are many events attached to datepicker, could you please share your vue template?

Comment: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-date-picker/#events